# Commit only to the output topic in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to build a Kafka Streams application that gets messages of type `A`.
For every `A` input, the application needs to produce **several bulks** of `B` outputs (a common flatMap operation).

I am seeking to implement it in a way that the application will commit to the output topic after every bulk (I call this *"subcommitting"*), and have a state of its *subcommits* (so it can resume to the *subcommits* it didn't do in a case of a failure).

I want the application to do the regular full commit only after it finished subcommitting all the bulks.

It seems like Processor API might help me since I can manage the state of the *subcommits*.

So,

1. Does this design make sense? (haven't seen anything like that when searching so I'm a bit suspicious)
2. How can I programmatically *subcommit*? (i.e commit only to the output topic)

Answer (score 1):

Committing offset in Kafka is based on input messages. Thus, if you have a single input record, that is `flatMap` into multiple output messages, you cannot split the commit into multiple. Either you commit the input message, or you don't.

There is no concept of committing output messages in Kafka.

Comment: [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) describes a transactional producer, that commits its messages, and a consumer configured with `"isolation.level" -> "read_committed"` will only poll the producer's committed messages. [It is also seems to be implemented in Kafka Streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams/). Can't I leverage it to my needs?

Comment: The smallest transaction possible is if you read a single message, and write all the corresponding output messages, and commit all write and the offset at once. If you would commit a partial write (ie, only some output messages) it would violate EOS semantics.